# Get first name from Facebook with django-socialregistration

Tags: python, django, facebook

With [django-socialregistration](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=django%20socialregistration&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration&ei=Xwv1TvPJIdLQ4QT52tCNCA&usg=AFQjCNF_RntVEkQcjWVSUWpUPjL9_uOAIA&sig2=UrjSNqKhfjlLe1_ezVGykw) what should I do to get the first name from Facebook at the moment of the Facebook Connect?

I tried to put these lines in `django-socialregistration/views.py`:

```
graph = request.facebook.graph 
fb_profile = graph.get_object("me")
user.first_name = fb_profile['first_name']
user.save()
```

in the method `post(self, request)` after `user = profile.authenticate()` but I get this error when I try to connect:

#### `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'`

Why? The error occurs at the first line `graph = request.facebook.graph`

The code of the django-socialregistration view:

```
class Setup(SocialRegistration, View):
    """
    Setup view to create new Django users from third party APIs.
    """
    template_name = 'socialregistration/setup.html'

    def get_form(self):
        """
        Return the form to be used. The return form is controlled
        with ``SOCIALREGISTRATION_SETUP_FORM``.
        """
        return self.import_attribute(FORM_CLASS)

    def get_username_function(self):
        """
        Return a function that can generate a username. The function
        is controlled with ``SOCIALREGISTRATION_GENERATE_USERNAME_FUNCTION``.
        """
        return self.import_attribute(USERNAME_FUNCTION)

    def get_initial_data(self, request, user, profile, client):
        """
        Return initial data for the setup form. The function can be
        controlled with ``SOCIALREGISTRATION_INITIAL_DATA_FUNCTION``.

        :param request: The current request object
        :param user: The unsaved user object
        :param profile: The unsaved profile object
        :param client: The API client
        """
        if INITAL_DATA_FUNCTION:
            func = self.import_attribute(INITAL_DATA_FUNCTION)
            return func(request, user, profile, client)
        return {}

    def generate_username_and_redirect(self, request, user, profile, client):
        """
        Generate a username and then redirect the user to the correct place.
        This method is called when ``SOCIALREGISTRATION_GENERATE_USERNAME``
        is set.

        :param request: The current request object
        :param user: The unsaved user object
        :param profile: The unsaved profile object
        :param client: The API client
        """
        func = self.get_username_function()

        user.username = func(user, profile, client)
        user.save()

        profile.user = user
        profile.save()

        user = profile.authenticate()

        self.send_connect_signal(request, user, profile, client)

        self.login(request, user)

        self.send_login_signal(request, user, profile, client)

        self.delete_session_data(request)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_next(request))

    def get(self, request):
        """
        When signing a new user up - either display a setup form, or
        generate the username automatically.
        """
        # I want some validation here, hacked up in the generic callback
        try:
            urlfrom = request.session['urlfrom']
            match = resolve(urlfrom)
            username, code = match.args
            checkcode, referrer, ticket = utils.register_validate(username, code)
        except:
            return http.HttpResponseServerError()
        # validation end

        try:
            user, profile, client = self.get_session_data(request)
        except KeyError:
            return self.render_to_response(dict(
                error=_("Social profile is missing from your session.")))

        if GENERATE_USERNAME:
            return self.generate_username_and_redirect(request, user, profile, client)

        form = self.get_form()(initial=self.get_initial_data(request, user, profile, client))

        return self.render_to_response(dict(form=form))

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Save the user and profile, login and send the right signals.
        """
        try:
            user, profile, client = self.get_session_data(request)
        except KeyError:
            return self.render_to_response(dict(
                error=_("A social profile is missing from your session.")))

        form = self.get_form()(request.POST, request.FILES,
            initial=self.get_initial_data(request, user, profile, client))

        if not form.is_valid():
            return self.render_to_response(dict(form=form))

        user, profile = form.save(request, user, profile, client)

        # validation count up referrals, tickets, etc.
        try:
            urlfrom = request.session['urlfrom']
            match = resolve(urlfrom)
            username, code = match.args
            checkcode, referrer, ticket = utils.register_validate(username, code)
        except:
            return http.HttpResponseServerError()
        utils.register_accounting(checkcode, referrer, ticket, user)

        user = profile.authenticate()

        self.send_connect_signal(request, user, profile, client)

        self.login(request, user)

        self.send_login_signal(request, user, profile, client)

        self.delete_session_data(request)

        # added by me
        graph = request.facebook.graph 
        fb_profile = graph.get_object("me")
        user.first_name = fb_profile['first_name']
        user.save()
        #

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_next(request))
```

Comment: What line does the exception occur on?

Comment: graph = request.facebook.graph

Comment: Is the user really authenticated with Django? The error seems similar to other questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439709/how-to-cater-for-anonymoususer-when-filtering-based-on-user)

Comment: Can you show us the code for the view? def foo(request)...

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes that error appears just after the "connect with facebook" button. The user use that button for signing up.

Comment: @JohnJohnGa I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

let me take a stab at it.  From where your code is it appears right above it you're killing the session `self.delete_session_data(request)`.  This might take away the session key or auth token.  Try your code above that line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have an AnonymousUser object in request.user when you access `request.facebook.graph`.  Check to see if your user [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) (more docs on [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#anonymous-users)):

```
request.user.is_authenticated()
```

Another thing to play with is [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) from inside the dev server (`manage.py runserver`).  The easiest way to use it is by using this line of code to put in a break point just before your code is bombing out:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

That will give you a prompt where you can look around at variables in context.